# AutoMapper not mapping nested complex type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following configuration.

```
public class AutoMapperProfile: Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
           CreateMap<DTO, Model>();
           CreateMap<InnerDTO, NavigationPropertyModel>();
        }
   }
```

In my code I have

```
Model.NavigationProperty = mapper.Map(DTO.InnerDTO, Model.NavigationProperty);
```

seems to work very well but

```
Model = mapper.Map(DTO, Model);
```

doesn't. (`InnerDTO` isn't mapped)

PS: mapper is an instance of the automapper.

I want to stick with the second approach since the DTO can have more properties than just the InnerDTO.

I tried using `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` but got an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Mapper not initialized.  Call
>   Initialize with appropriate configuration.  If you are trying to use
>   mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do
>   not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods,   and if you're
>   using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you
>   pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.'

Comment: Maybe I got your question wrong but with `automapper`, as long as you define the mappings for all properties you have, which could be properties of the others, `automapper` knows how to map them correctly. You don't need to manually call `Model.NavigationProperty = mapper.Map()`.

Comment: -1 downvoted because you have not provided a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You have not provided how mapper was instantiated nor the definitions of your models.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I could reproduce this behavior with a general `Model` with `NavigationProperty`. Wait for op to check whether my answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure sub-property for `CreateMap<DTO, Model>();`.

```
        public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<DTO, Model>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.NavigationPropertyModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InnerDTO));
        CreateMap<InnerDTO, NavigationPropertyModel>();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Possibly what you are missing is to add your `AutoMapperProfile` class in `Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Automapper conf
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(configure => {
        // Add your profile class here
        configure.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
    });
    // Creating instance of automapper for dependency injection
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    // More complex code here...
}
```

Subsequently, by dependency injection, you use automapper. In my particular case, I do it in the following way:

```
[Route("api/Permiso")]
[ApiController]
public class PermisoController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IBusinessLogicHelper _blh;

    public PermisoController(BusinessLogicHelper blh, IMapper mapper) {
        _blh = blh;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        try {
            // Get raw data from entities
            var resultsRaw = _blh.GetDataRaw();
            if (resultsRaw == null) {
                return NotFound();
            }
            // Mapping data from entity to DTO
            var resultsDTO = _mapper.Map<ReturnDataDTO>(resultsRaw);
            return Ok(resultsDTO);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Custom ObjectResult for InternalServerError
            return new InternalServerErrorObjectResult(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why negative vote for the question and answers? I need an explanation :|